# How to make this method to be async despite of not supporting the 'await' keyword

Tags: c#, async-await, postman, http-post

I'm trying to make a method that runs as an async method. The problem is the longest part is not 'awaitable' (not support the 'await' keyword ). I based my code using this link: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await).

Some parts in my code have taken from Postman - HTTP POST to an API.

```
        private async Task<byte[]> PostRequestToOptiRoutesAsync()
        {
        string urlCallBack = u.Trim(this.URLAchzraR4M);
        var client = new RestClient(u.Trim(PrmtrimGlobliim_407_2.Mchrozt));
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddParameter("hfd_xml", u.Trim(BlovXMLBkshaOPT).Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace("\t", ""));
        request.AddParameter("link", urlCallBack);

        //UNTIL HERE - IT IS SYNC CODE AND NOT RELEVANT 

        //FROM HERE - THE POST TO THE API
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request); // client.Execute is not awaitable - THE PROBLEMATIC ROW IS HERE
        return u.UTF8FromAnsi(response.Content); // u.UTF8FromAnsi CONVERT THE RESULT- IGNORE IT
        }

        private async Task GetOptimalRoute()
        {
            Task<byte[]> result =  PostRequestToOptiRoutesAsync();
            await result;
        }
```

The problem is that when I call GetOptimalRoute() using VS debug, my thread is not immediately moved to the next row, but it acts like sync code. It pauses for few seconds - unlike the code in the link above!!
How can I resolve this issue and make this code to be async?

Comment: wrap it with another thread?

Comment: can you please provide more information about your `RestClient`? because the one i know has an `ExecuteAsync`-method..

Comment: @Franz Gleichmann  - Can you show me an example?

Comment: @Selvin I meant to the main thread

Comment: @חייםחדד you _do_ know that basic research is an important skill? https://restsharp.dev/getting-started/getting-started.html#asynchronous-calls

Comment: if you have sync api then you may wrap it to another thread to not block main thread ... with something like `var  result = await Task.Run(() => GetResultViaSyncAPI());`

Comment: @Franz Gleichmann Searching...

Comment: @חייםחדד you do not need to search now, as i have posted a _link to the manual with an example_ in my comment....... but you _could_ provide the requested information about _your_ RestClient, if you'd like. for example: what nuget package, and what version it is.